# sbt 0.13.13 resolving key references hanging

Tags: scala, sbt

After upgrading to sbt 0.13.13 on a large project, I noticed that sbt hangs on *Resolving Key References* for anywhere from 3-5 minutes. I have started the debug mode from sbt and it finishes at, any leads as to what the problem may be?

```
[debug] All initially invalidated sources: Set()
[debug] Copy resource mappings:
[debug]
[info] Resolving key references (13074 settings) ...
```

Comment: Could you share your build? I assume you've already tried `rm -rf ~/.ivy2 && git clean -fdx`

Comment: By any chance, did you manage to solve your issue since then?
I am facing the exact same problem...